# Getting all numbers below a certain integer in Swift

Tags: swift, swift3

I was wondering how to be able to get all the numbers below a certain integer. So like if the number is 5, it should get 4,3,2,1.

Comment: you can run a loop.

Comment: What is the expected return type? `[Int]`? `String`? `Range<Int>`?

Comment: easy `Array(1..<n)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `for` loop, a `range`, and `reverse` it:

```
let start = 5
// The range is 1..<start
// It begins at 1 and goes to 1 less than the value in start
for number in (1..<start).reversed() {
  print(number)
}

// Output:
// 4
// 3
// 2
// 1
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use the to iterate on a range in reverse order**

```
for index in stride(from: 4, through: 1, by: -1) {
    print(index)
}
```

Comment: `let numbers = stride(from: number.advanced(by: -1), through: 1, by: -1).map{$0}`